# JQuery doesn't remove class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm getting in trouble when I try to only REMOVE a class when I click a `<a>` tag. Adding class works perfectly, but `removeClass()` doesn't.
I have on my html:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <h4>Ambiente</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Baño</a></li>
                        <li><a id="ambienteCocina">Cocina</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dormitorio</li>
                        <li><a>Jardin</li>
                        <li><a>Living</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10 " style="border-left: 1px solid black">
                    <div id="contenedorOpcionesBano" class="opcionesAmbiente opcionesAmbienteActivo">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And then it works:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ambienteCocina', function(e){ 
    $("#contenedorOpcionesBano").addClass("opcionesAmbienteActivo");
});
```

But it doesn't!

```
$(document).on('click', '#ambienteCocina', function(e){ 
    $("#contenedorOpcionesBano").removeClass("opcionesAmbienteActivo");
});
```

Any idea?

EDIT::

I also tried this way, which still is not working

html modified:

```
<li><a id="ambienteCocina" onclick="cambiarAmbiente()">Cocina</a></li>
```

.JS Modified:

```
function cambiarAmbiente() {
    $("#contenedorOpcionesBaño").removeClass("opcionesAmbienteActivo");
    console.log("CHanged");
}
```

However, the log on console is displayed!

Comment: So you have 2 click handlers, one adds and the other one removes the class?

Comment: Oh no, it's the same click handler, what i mean is that when i edit this to addClass() it works, but when i try to removeClass(), it doesn't.

Comment: no, it works alright ... what does removing `opcionesAmbienteActivo` supposed to achieve (the class is removed)

Comment: @JaromandaX What code have you tested? Which works with the function or the other?. Neither of them are working to me

Comment: I tried **your code** ... see https://jsfiddle.net/tgdq6mw0/ - note, that div `contenedorOpcionesBano` will only be displayed if it includes class `opcionesAmbienteActivo` ... on clicking `#ambienteCocina` the class is removed, and the div no longer displays - proving that the class is removed

Comment: I mean, your code as it is in the question, nothing will be obvious, unless you inspect the DOM in the developer tools - and you'll see the class disappear when you click the appropriate list item

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you! That was an error on my .css file, i'll answer the post right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my .css file,

I had those styles:

```
 .opcionesAmbiente {
    display: none;
}
.opcionesAmbiente .opcionesAmbienteActivo {
    display: block;
}
```

And it means that .opcionesAmbienteActive must be child of .opcionesAmbiente.
So it was fixed by this way:

```
.opcionesAmbiente {
    display: none;
}
.opcionesAmbiente.opcionesAmbienteActivo {
    display: block;
}
```

What refers to an element which has bot .opcionesAmbiente AND .opcionesAmbienteActivo

Answer (score 1):

in this snippet you can verify that the code is working.
maybe you can post your css

```js
$(document).on('click', '#ambienteCocina', function(e){ 
    $("#contenedorOpcionesBano").removeClass("opcionesAmbienteActivo");
});
```

```css
.opcionesAmbienteActivo{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h4>Ambiente</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Baño</a></li>
            <li><a id="ambienteCocina">Cocina</a></li>
            <li><a>Dormitorio</a></li>
            <li><a>Jardin</a></li>
            <li><a>Living</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-10 " style="border-left: 1px solid black">
      <div id="contenedorOpcionesBano" class="opcionesAmbiente opcionesAmbienteActivo">
        opcionesAmbienteActivo
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

just as an observation, in the list, the last 3 `<a>` are not closed

If you want to add or remove the class I recommend you use [jQuery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). that allow Add or remove classes depending on either the class's presence

Answer (score -2):

you can try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ambienteCocina', function(e){ 
    $("#contenedorOpcionesBano").toggleClass("opcionesAmbienteActivo");
});
```

or

> Use off before using on